# security help regarding php registration

Tags: php, mysql, sql

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Best way to prevent SQL injection in PHP?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60174/best-way-to-prevent-sql-injection-in-php)

This is a simple registration I made in PHP. 
I just want to know how to make it really secure, as I am new to PHP, so examples would help also. All in all, any resources or guidance would be great.

```
<?php

$email = $_POST["email"];
$password = $_POST["password"];
$fname = $_POST["first_name"];
$lname = $_POST["last_name"];

$db = "mydatabase";
$connect = mysql_connect("localhost","root","");
if(!$connect){
    die('Could not connect.');  
}

$query = "INSERT INTO users (id, email, password, first_name, last_name) VALUES (DEFAULT, '".$email."', '".$password."', '".$fname."', '".$lname."')";

mysql_select_db($db, $connect);

if(!mysql_query($query)){
    echo 'Failed: '.mysql_error();
}
else{
    echo 'You have registered.';
}

mysql_close($connect);

?>
```

and this is the register input form

```
<html>
<head>
</html>
<body>

<form action="new_user_db.php" method="POST">
    <input type="text" name="first_name" placeholder="First Name" required><br>
    <input type="text" name="last_name" placeholder="Last Name" required><br>
    <input type="email" name="email" placeholder="E-mail" required><br>
    <input type="password" name="password" placeholder="Password" required><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Register">
</form>

</body>
</html>
```

thanks for all your feedback!

Comment: The first thing you can do is to stop using the `mysql_*` functions, they are no longer maintained and community has begun the [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ) . Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you cannot decide, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help to choose. If you want to learn, [here is a good PDO-related tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC).

Comment: Put your code out of the webroot.

Comment: Email: `someone@someplace.com`. Password: `password`. First name: `First`. Last name: `Last');DROP TABLE users;--`. *There, the `users` table is gone.*

Comment: Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions to write new code. They are no longer maintained and the community has begun [deprecation process](http://goo.gl/KJveJ). See the *[red box](http://goo.gl/GPmFd)*? Instead you should learn about [prepared statements](http://goo.gl/vn8zQ) and use either [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli). If you can't decide which, [this article](http://goo.gl/3gqF9) will help you. If you pick PDO, [here is good tutorial](http://goo.gl/vFWnC). Also see [Why shouldn't I use `mysql` functions in PHP?](http://goo.gl/ycnmO)

Comment: @vascowhite: You're using an older version of this comment :) See the one above me for the newer version ^

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I don't think that really matters.

Comment: @vascowhite: Meh, the major difference is the red box, and the new "Why shouldn't I use `mysql_*` functions" question.

Comment: @MadaraUchiha I refer you to my previous comment :)

Comment: Bobby Tables yet again.  You'd think after the XKCD comic got so well known people would finally stop making that mistake. http://xkcd.com/327/

Comment: SQL injection is definitely something to worry about, but in this case, Bobby Tables just causes an error.  By default, `mysql_query` refuses to run two statements in one string.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Security Issues:

1. Use [MySQLi](https://www.php.net/mysqli)/[PDO](https://www.php.net/pdo). mysql_ functions are deprecated.
2. Stop using the **root** account to run your mysql queries. Create a new database user with the minimum required privileges
3. Finally (unrelated to PHP), look into SSL and securing the movement of credentials from client to server.

Also, not a security risk but...

Having your credentials in **every single** PHP file that uses it is bad practice. Put it in a **separate PHP** and [include](http://php.net/manual/en/function.include.php)/[require](http://php.net/manual/en/function.require.php) it, whenever you want to make a connection. That prevents you having to make several changes when changing database server/user/password.

Answer (score 1):

Use a Prepared Statement

```
$db = mysqli_connect($dbserver, $dbuser, $dbpass,$dbname);

$sql = "insert into mytable (mycol1, mycol2) values (?,?)";

$statement = $db->prepare($sql);

$statement -> bindparam("ss",$myval1, $myval2)'

mysqli_stmt_execute(#statement);
```